# ng-options & ng-repeat: why angular model isn't bind?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I bind the `select` elements to ng-model `family`, which refers to an element of `font.families` array, **Angular doesn't bind what is selected**. The array stays empty, with just the first `null` element.

But when I bind the `select` elements to `font.families[$index]`, the binding is effective.

```js
// Javascript
$scope.font.families = [null]; // Used to create an empty first line in the form

$scope.families = [
  { name: "Foo", parent: "Bar" },
  { name: "Doo", parent: "Dar" }
];

$scope.mainFamilies = [
  { name: "Bar", children: ["Foo", "Baz"] },
  { name: "Dar", children: ["Doo", "Hoo"] }
];
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

Font families : {{ font.families }}

<div ng-repeat="family in font.families track by $index">

    Family : {{ family }}

    <ng-form name="familyRow">

    <select ng-options="fam as fam.name group by fam.parent for fam in families"
            ng-model="font.families[$index]"
            name="family">
        <option disabled value="">—</option>
    </select>

    <select ng-options="mainFam.name as mainFam.name for mainFam in mainFamilies"
            ng-model="font.families[$index].parent"
            name="mainFamily">
        <option disabled value="">—</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DCd1qgFrwKNAMQ2yiXPT?p=preview) to illustrate the problem.

**How comes?**

Comment: use `$parent` in `ng-model="font.families[$index].parent"` will be `ng-model="font.families[$index].$parent"`

Comment: @Vineet `parent` is a property of `$scope.families` objects, not the Angular variable

Comment: Okay. Now i can understand after watching your object

Answer (score 0):

Here's my understanding of the issue:
**Case 1 (Working)**: You're using ng-model="model.families[$index]". In this case when you make a selection here's what happens:

```
model.families[0] -> Your selection
```

**Case 2 (Not working)**: You're using ng-model="family". In this case this is what is happening:

```
family -> model.families[0] -> null
```

When you make the selection:
family -> new selection

```
model.families[0] -> null
```

The problem is that in 2nd case, the assignment causes the family variable to be assigned a new value altogether and the source array remains the same.

You can further verify this by adding these statements in your html:

```
family: {{family}}  
model.families: {{model.families[$index]}}
Are they equal?: {{familly === model.families[$index]}}
```

Comment: Yes, but why is that? Why is `family` desolidarized of `model.families[$index]`?

Comment: family is just a variable which points to an item in the array. Any variable can be made to point to a different object. If we make family point to a different object it is no longer connected to model.families. Whereas when you use $index then you're effectively pointing model.families[$index] to the new object. Which is what you want to do.

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with Angular or ngRepeat. You can emulate the same behavior in simple JavaScript with for loop.

Comment: I got that, but I wonder why `family` doesn't point to `model.families[$index]` here, as it is supposed to. It is supposed to be `null` unless I assign it a new value, in my case an object, do you agree?

Comment: Maybe this would help: stackoverflow.com/questions/17872317/javascript-variables-as-object-pointers